# OSB - Getting BUFFER_UNDERFLOW in while calling an external service with SSL

Tags: osb

I am struggling with an error and i do not find the solution.
I have a server with a OSB and weblogic 10.3.6.0 and running with java 1.6 211 (it accepts TLSv1.1).

I already put the certificate in the cacerts file and try many different solutions I found in internet but I am still getting the next error.

```
<Mar 5, 2019 3:33:14 PM UTC> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '22' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLCONTEXT: Got SSLContext, protocol=TLS, provider=SunJSSE>

<Mar 5, 2019 3:33:14 PM UTC> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '22' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.setEnabledCipherSuites(String[]): value=TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV.>

<Mar 5, 2019 3:33:14 PM UTC> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '22' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.setEnabledProtocols(String[]): value=SSLv2Hello,SSLv3,TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2.>

<Mar 5, 2019 3:33:14 PM UTC> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '22' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.setEnableSessionCreation(boolean): value=true.>

<Mar 5, 2019 3:33:14 PM UTC> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '22' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.setUseClientMode(boolean): value=true.>

<Mar 5, 2019 3:33:14 PM UTC> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '22' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.setWantClientAuth(boolean): value=false.>

<Mar 5, 2019 3:33:14 PM UTC> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '22' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.setNeedClientAuth(boolean): value=false.>

<Mar 5, 2019 3:33:14 PM UTC> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '22' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.setNeedClientAuth(boolean): value=false.>

<Mar 5, 2019 3:33:14 PM UTC> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '22' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.setUseClientMode(boolean): value=true.>

<Mar 5, 2019 3:33:14 PM UTC> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '22' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.setUseClientMode(boolean): value=true.>

<Mar 5, 2019 3:33:14 PM UTC> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '22' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.wrap(ByteBuffer,ByteBuffer) called: result=Status = OK HandshakeStatus = NEED_UNWRAP
bytesConsumed = 0 bytesProduced = 82.>

<Mar 5, 2019 3:33:14 PM UTC> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '22' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.unwrap(ByteBuffer,ByteBuffer[]) called: result=Status = BUFFER_UNDERFLOW HandshakeStatus = NEED_UNWRAP
bytesConsumed = 0 bytesProduced = 0.>

<Mar 5, 2019 3:33:14 PM UTC> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '22' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: Exception occurred during SSLEngine.unwrap(ByteBuffer,ByteBuffer[]).
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:188)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1614)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1582)
```

Any idea or help would be highly appreciate it.
I read that maybe the best solution would be to upgrade the java in the server but due the current conditions in the project, it seems like the last option.

Regards.

Comment: What you are getting is a handshake failure. The BUFFER_UNDERFLOW is entirely incidental. You need to look at the peer logs to see what is going on here.

Comment: A trust issue would log a message like 'PKIX path building failed'. Is this 1-way or 2-way SSL? As you specify TLS 1.1, does the source require specific handshakes or algoritms? Is SNI required?